# How to store Hashed Password to the Database using Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I need to store Password as hashed to the database, I was able to has the password but when I submit my form the password stores as un-hashed,

Here's my controller Store Function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $hash = ['password' => Hash::make($request)];

    //dd($hash);
    // HASHED PASSWORD WAS DISPLAYED HERE 


    $user = User::create($this->validateRequest());

    dd('User Created');
}
```

Here's my Validate Function

```
private function validateRequest()
{

    return request()->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'phone' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

I tried to do this in my Store Function (But it didn't work !!)

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $hash = ['password' => Hash::make($request)];

        $user = User::create($this->validateRequest($hash));
        dd('User Created');
   }
```

Is there a way where I can store the hashed password to the DB by this way ?

Or else do I need to stick to this way ;( ?

```
$user = User::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'phone' => $request['phone'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
```

I just wanted my controllers to be clean with few lines of code.

Can someone please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: you would have to modify the array that you get from `validateRequest` to add the hashed password

Comment: @lagbox How can I modify it. Please show me an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mutator in your `User` model so every time you set the password, it'll be hashed.

```php
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
}
```

This way, you `store` method would look like this:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::create($this->validateRequest());
    dd('User Created');
}
```

---

This is outside the scope of this question but just one more advice: you should use a form request class (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests) in order to reduce the amount of code in your controllers (among other advantages).

Answer (score 0):

You're validating the `request` after changing the value of `password`, for this reason password confirmation can't be validated and returning with validation error.

Validate the `request` first, then replace the `password` value with hashed one.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
      'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
      'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
      'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
      'phone' => 'required',
    ]);
    
    $request->merge(['password' => Hash::make($request->input('password'))]);

    $user = User::create($request->all());
    dd($user);
}
```

Comment: I don't want the validation to be inside my function, is there a way that I can use the validate function which I have created already ?